# Rails: How do I print the request parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3 application and I want to print in the view the request parameters. How do I do it?

Edit:

The purpose is to see what is being sent in a Form.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I would use `debug(params)`. That will give you a nicely formatted view of them.

Comment: It gives me info about the controller and the action being called. But my purpose is to see what is being sent by a Form. How can I print that info?

Comment: It gives me this:  --- !map:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess 
action: index
controller: course_groups

Comment: That just means your form params aren't available to your view in this instance, which is probably your problem. If the params from the form were available they would show up.

Comment: You can also see the params from your form in the WEBrick log if you're developing on local.

Comment: I develop with passenger, so I just __tail -f log/development.log__ . I managed to see what I wanted that way, thanks

Comment: Outdated! See answer below. Use params.inspect

Comment: It's not outdated.  The `debug` method is a great way to see what's in the `params`.  And I agree with @Nerian that tailing the log is helpful to see much more info.

Comment: Doesn't appear to work in Rails 5.1 `NoMethodError (undefined method \`debug' for`

Answer (score 90):

If you wanted to print all of the parameters, the easiest way would be to use the inspect

```
puts params.inspect
```

or better, use the Rails logger

```
Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
```

In your html/ERB, you can use

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

Comment: Where does the output for `puts params.inspect` get printed? Browser's console window or what?

Answer (score 15):

Learnt this from the Ruby Hero James Edward Gray II on [this episode of Ruby Rogues podcast](http://rubyrogues.com/debugging-in-ruby/)  which I highly recommend. `raise` is a swiss army knife for inspecting anything in your Rails code which prints it nicely on your browser.

> raise params.inspect

Comment: A lot of the time I wish there was no min character limit on comments so I could just go 

Answer (score 13):

Parameters are stored in the `params` hash. For example, if there was a `title` parameter, you could display it in your view using `<%= params[:title] %>`.

Comment: But I want to see the information that is displayed when there is an error. You get to see all the things about the request, the parameters, etc.

Answer (score 4):

`pretty_print` also can be useful, in ruby and rails apps both

```
pp params
```

pretty_print doc: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html

Answer (score 4):

Something like

```
<%= params.inspect %>
```

works, but what I would like to add is the following [gem and Chrome plugin](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) which was literally an eye-opener.

I am putting it here because I think it will help people check out params hashes, see SQL queries or view Errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use for models, controllers, etc.

```
puts YAML::dump(params)
```

Source: [Ruby / Rails alternative to PHP print_r() and var_dump()](http://source.mihelac.org/2006/3/31/ruby-rails-alternative-to-php-print_r-and-var_dump/)

For views:

```
DebugHelper’s debug(object)
```

In your case:

```
DebugHelper’s debug(params)
```

Answer (score 3):

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-articles

> When a form is submitted, the fields of the form are sent to Rails as parameters. These parameters can then be referenced inside the controller actions, typically to perform a particular task. To see what these parameters look like, change the create action to this:

```
def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end
```

---

The response when POST'ing a form to the targeted #create route would be a plain-text hash output of `params[:article]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ap params.to_unsafe_h
```

Example output:

```
[19] pry(#<AssessmentsController>)> ap params.to_unsafe_h
{
                  "utf8" => "✓",
    "authenticity_token" => "",
            "assessment" => {
        "form_field_10" => "0",
        "form_field_12" => "1"
    },
                "commit" => "Create Assessment",
            "controller" => "assessments",
                "action" => "create"
}
=> nil
```

Uses https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342607