# Send multidimensional array from js to sinatra

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, sinatra

Currently I am trying to find a way to send a multidimensional array from jQuery via ajax to the server. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save",
    data: ["string", [["string1", "string2"], ["string 3", "string 4"]]],
    // it is arbitrary how many of the ["string", "string"] type arrays
    // there could be in the second element of the containing array.
    callback: save, // Don't worry about this function, it currently doesn't get called.
    dataType: "text"
});
```

What is happening now is that when the server receives it and `puts params.inspect` it outputs `{undefined=>""}`. I think that the solution may lie in converting the array to a string in jQuery and converting it back after the server receives it, but I don't know.

P.S. For those of you who could do this in vanilla js but not jQuery, all I'm trying to do is send a ajax post request to `/save` with 1 parameter: `["string", [["string1", "string2"], ["string 3", "string 4"]]]`.

**UPDATE**

I used google chromes inspect element menu to look at the request sent to the server. The server responded as expected, and when I looked at the sent form data I saw this (when sending {"1": ["match", [["a", "a"], ["s", "s"]]]}):

```
1[]:match
1[1][0][]:a
1[1][0][]:a
1[1][1][]:s
1[1][1][]:s
```

Does this signify that the form was sent correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't sending a key/value pair ... only a value which happens to be an array.

Try sending as :

```
var myArray =  ["string", [["string1", "string2"], ["string 3", "string 4"]]];

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/save",
    data: { postKeyName : myArray},    
    callback: save, 
    dataType: "text"
});
```

jQuery will take care of form ending the array internally and you just need to receive array in the post param you name in lieu of `postKeyName`

Comment: I'm confused... Could you please write some ruby/psudo-ruby or explain how to retrieve the array in ruby?

Comment: Also why do I have to send a key/value pair? Why can't I just send the array?

Comment: because default form post is comprised of key/value .... you can't just send value with form encoding. Think of a regular form which has `name` and `value` for each control. You could send as json in post body then parse the body and decode the json if all you want to send is array

Comment: Let me just try what you have then, and if it works I'll accept you answer. Thank you so much for the prompt response!!

Comment: ok, I tried `data: {"1": myArray}` with `myArray` as the array I posted and when I used `puts params.inspect` in ruby, I got `{}`.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and seems like it should work, and I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: i don't know ruby but why would it be `puts` ? Is that how you receive a normal form? Unless you change the `contentType` receiving this ajax is exactly the same as receiving a normal form using post

Comment: `puts params.inspect` should log to the console `puts` the parameters received `params.inspect` as shown in the second answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837859/rails-how-do-i-print-the-request-parameters. (the first answer is outdated as you can see in the comments).