# Format Params in Rails Server Logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pretty-print, awesomeprint

I have a webhooks controller, and i want to be able to view the params that get printed to my server logs in development in a nice readable format.  Is awesome_print good for this?  I'm trying to use prettyprint, example below, but the format is still not very readable.

Trying to use prettyprint to format params

```
  class DwollaWebhooksController < WebhooksController
  require 'pp'


    def create
      pp params

      case params[:topic]
        when 'customer_funding_source_verified'
          puts '----------customer_funding_source_verified-----------------'
      end

    end
```

Here's what that output looks like

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"57dec892", "resourceId"=>"a0d172yx", "topic"=>"customer_bank_transfer_completed",...} permitted: false>
```

I'm looking for something that at least has proper indentation, multiple lines, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to render the parameters in a "pretty" way, you can convert them to hash. Although as you have unpermitted params, you should use `to_unsafe_h()`, which gives you an unsafe, unfiltered `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` representation of the parameters. So:

```
pp params.to_unsafe_h
```

which will output something like:

```
{"id"=>"57dec892",
 "resourceId"=>"a0d172yx",
 "topic"=>"customer_bank_transfer_completed"}
```