# java - How do I print attributes and values of a request object?

Tags: java

I have a request object that probably belons to this class: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/RequestFacade.html

I am trying to print the names of the attributes and their values. This is my futile attempt.

```
Enumeration rns = request.getAttributeNames();

while (rns.hasMoreElements()) {
    Object param = rns.nextElement();
    out.println("\nattribute name: " + param.toString());
    out.println("attribute value: " + request.getAttribute(param.toString()));
}
```

What I am missing? In another language there is a trivial answer to such question. How different it is done in java?
[Rails: How do I print the request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837859/rails-how-do-i-print-the-request-parameters)

## my hardcoded attempt

```
   Enumeration rns = request.getAttributeNames();
    while (rns.hasMoreElements()) {
        out.println("\nattribute name: " + rns.nextElement() );
    }
    // i have copied the logs output from above and edited it to create the array below
    String[] madAttrs = { "dayToGraph",
                          "yearFromGraph",
                          "yaxis",
                          "yearToGraph",
                          "monthToGraph",
                          "monthFromGraph",
                          "currentMachine",
                          "onlyGraph",
                          "currentSample",
                          "currentAnalyte",
                          "dayFromGraph",
                          "analyteid"};
    // then I got what I want.
    for (String an : madAttrs) {
        out.println("sttribute " + an);
        out.println("the value is: "+ request.getAttribute(an));
    }
```

But how do I do it without hardcoding the attributes in the array?

Comment: And your problem is? What exactly does not work? Is it a servlet?

Comment: Do you search for `Session` attributes?

Comment: What is not working ? Do you have an exception ? What is showing up ? What would you like instead ?

Comment: @ruby_object please post your JSP and not just the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

#### Not the answer you want, but the real answer to your question

Leave the 1990s in the past and stop putting java code in JSP files.

Instead receive the message in a servlet (or Spring handler) and do java work therein.
Next create the display values and put them in some context (perhaps the response) and dispatch the request to your JSP page.

#### Don't do this

If you refuse to do the above,
import the required classes into your JSP file.
I will not include the syntax for importing files into a JSP file,
but be assured,
Google has fewer compunctions about such things than do I.

Comment: Sorry for the dv, but you didn't answer the question. It is always good to state best practices, after answering an issue. For example we might be interested in a simple snippet for debugging purposes that just works.